# Can app lockers really work?

Tags: applications

There seem to be many app-locking applications out there but I wonder what do they really do? I imagine there might be many solutions to app-locking, but is it possible to really prevent someone from accessing certain apps without modifying their code? Is it not possible to just run the app e.g. from terminal or something like that?

Note that I'm not asking about a very secure solution (e.g. I know that if the memory is not encrypted then you can read from hardware). I would just like to know if disabling all locks is not as simple as disabling e.g. Ultimate App Guard where you can press back button to go to the "locked" app.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623767/how-do-android-app-lock-applications-work